# 29 Word Seed Phrase Recovery

Tags: ether, metamask, myetherwallet, recovery, passphrase

around 2018-04-14 I opened an eth wallet, which I am positive was with MetaMask. I have found a file on my computer that contains a **29 word** seed phrase. I saved this file and labeled it "Do not delete, eth seed phrase". My issue is that no provider seems to have a 29 word seed phrase.

I've tried everything I can at this point to try and recover the seed phrase by other means like my AppData folder but I cant find anything helpful.

Is there any way I can make use of this seed phrase I saved? Maybe with an older version of MetaMask or some other provider which uses that long of a phrase? Can I convert the longer phrase into a shorter one?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Use the code in the following answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/85244/i-had-version-uped-my-metamask-on-firefox-it-makes-my-metamask-account-renewed/150395#150395

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a legit seed phrase you can import it into most of the wallets. The seed phrase standard is called [BIP-32](https://wolovim.medium.com/ethereum-201-mnemonics-bb01a9108c38). However the amount of seed words - 29 - strikes me odd. Usually you have 12 or 24 words and I have never heard of 29 words one. Maybe you inserted in some fake words?

Comment: darn I was hopping that at some point long ago some wallet used 29 words, guess not. knowing my dumb self adding fake words is exactly what I would have done to trick the hackers of the world :P as usually it only bites me! I will begin the exercise of trying all possible combinations and hopefully I get lucky.

Comment: would you happen to know if it was a 12 or 24 word phrase that would have been generated? That may help me narrow down how many fake words I added.

Comment: do words have to be unique in the phrase?

Comment: I do not know, but you can find the answer by studying BIP-32 specification. I have never seen a seed phrase with a duplicate word.

Comment: Mnemonic phrases are specified in BIP-39, not in BIP-32. The latter only defines how public and private keys should be derived from some kind of master seed, and BIP-39 specifies how to generate a master seed from a mnemonic phrase. BIP-39 mnemonic phrases can have a length of 12 to 24 words (including lengths like 15, 18, 21 words, though these are not common), but more than 24 words is technically not valid in the spec.

Answer (score 2):

Do you remember if you ever used Sia?  That's the only wallet I've used in the past with a 29 word recovery phrase.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, gave it a try but no it didnt recover anything :( I am almost positive it was meta mask

Answer (score 0):

No, words in seed phrases do not have to be unique.  I have a seed phrase for a 12 word wal that contains a duplicate word, which I noted as amusing, at the time.